Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'. > 2 files found with path || libgojni.so || Flutter
When the bellow 2 Flutter Package dependencies are added :
openvpn_flutter
and,
flutter_v2ray
the bellow error is shows :
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction
2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libgojni.so' from inputs

this happens for all four architecture
tried picking first one
android {
    // ...
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libgojni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libgojni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libgojni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libgojni.so'
    }
}

Also tried exclude this library in packagingOptions.
But it doesnt load the library for flutter_v2ray and shows internal error when I try work with the flutter_v2ray package
How can i resolve this?
